# Generate iPhone application Archive

Tags: ios, xcode5, archive, cfbundleidentifier

I want to submit my iPhone application to the app store. But I'm not able to do that due to following error.

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. The executable name, as reported by CFBundleExecutable in the info.plist file, may not contain any of these characters: \ [ ] { } parenthesis . + *" at Software Assets (MZItmspSoftwareAssestPackage)
```

**There isn't any problem in generating ipa file for Ad-Hoc testing.** I even tried with creating new project from Xcode but still the error continues. I am using Xcode-5.0

Comment: is it possible to give your plist to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to all who have tried to pull me out from this issue. I really don't know what was the problem but this morning i create new project, add new controllers and other needed files. Just copy all the codes in relative files. Build with certificate that i generated and was using last night. Submit in App Store and it did submitted. I didn't change in Info.plist file. No needed to generate new Distribution profile. Just create new project.

Many many thanks to @Mani, @Mani vannam, @Deepesh

Answer (score 0):

Just `Edit` this **executable file(name) setting in info.plist** which wouldn't contain special character as like error above. Check this screenshot. check [this apple's doc(CFBundleExecutable)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-101909)

[image]

[Refer this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724136/xcode-falsely-claims-cfbundleexecutable-to-be-null)

**Note:** This type of error doesn't occur with ad-hoc provisioning profile.

Comment: Hi Mani. Thanks for very quick replay. It is same as you mention here

Comment: @JayPandya Then check your bundle identifier which is contain special character. Just check this by editing as Your_target_Name(with out special character like space...etc) which match with your target name?

Comment: Dont i have to mention Bundle Identifier same as what i mention in my apple developer account instead of give same as target name? Like, com.something.deviceapp

Comment: No. It's could not be bundle identifier's name. because, here you've to mention about binary name(executable file name).. see my updated answer. I means, no need to be target name. I Just give example about like this...

Comment: Hi Mani. I have tried what you suggested last. But still giving me same error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be with your project name or target name so please rename it by single click on the target. have your project name with out any special characters like []{}

Comment: Hi Mani vannan. As i added in my question that i have tried by creating new project. But no change in error

Comment: I think you have not read my question properly. Anyway i am using Xcode - 5.0

Comment: please create provision profile for App store and try it out... and try to upload app using application loader

Comment: i am doing the same. Trying to submit app with App Store distribution profile

Answer (score 0):

You are use the **Ad-hoc distribution provision profile** for upload the app in app store ....

According to Apple for upload the app you are use the **app store distribution provision profile**.

So error generate .....

Create the new provision for upload app store but No need the change bundle id....

[image]

and check Architecture
[image]

and solve your problem

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your replay but i have created App Store distribution profile. And using same for submission

Comment: you change in both section in build setting

Comment: Project-> Target-> Build Settings-> and Project-> Build Settings ->